# Реализовать поиск в Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно реализовать поиск в таблице Treeview, по всем параметрам.
Проблема в том что я не понимаю как переделать эту функцию под мою таблицу.
Функция поиска находиться на 570 строке.
Код функции:

```
    def search(self):
        search_entry_get = self.entry_Poisk.get()
        id_to_select = ()
    
        if search_entry_get == '':
            all_tags = root.call(str(self.tree), "tag", "names")
            tags_to_select = tuple(filter(lambda tag: search_entry_get.lower() in tag.lower(), all_tags))
            for sorted_tag in tags_to_select:
                id_to_select += self.tree.tag_has(sorted_tag)
    
        self.tree.selection_set(id_to_select)
```

Мой код программы:

```
    import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import ttk
import csv
from turtle import pd
import openpyxl
import pandas
import os



class Main(tk.Frame): #Главное окно
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()

    def init_main(self):
        toolbar = tk.Frame(self, bg="#d7d8e0", bd=10)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

        btn_open_dialog1 = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Заявка", command=lambda: self.open_dialog1(), bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        btn_open_dialog2 = tk.Button(toolbar, text="ЗаявкаГАИ", command=lambda: self.open_dialog2(), bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        btn_open_dialog3 = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Администратор", command=lambda: self.open_dialog3(), bg="#d7d8e0",
                                     bd=0, compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


    def open_dialog2(self):
        ZaiavkaGAI()

    def open_dialog1(self):
        Zaiavka()

    def open_dialog3(self):
        Admin()


class Sotrudniki(tk.Toplevel): # Сотрудники

    def PRINT_SOT(self):
        os.startfile("Sotrudniki.csv", "print")

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.Treeview = None
        self.title("Сотрудники")
        self.geometry("600x348+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)


        toolbar2 = tk.Frame(self, bg='#d8d9e9', bd=0)
        toolbar2.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        btn_open_dialog8 = tk.Button(toolbar2, text="Добавить сотрудника",
                                     command=lambda: self.init_Dobavlenie_Sotrudnika(),
                                     bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog8.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog9 = tk.Button(toolbar2, text="Удалить сотрудника", command=lambda: self.Del_SOT(),
                                     bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog9.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog11 = tk.Button(toolbar2, text="На печать",
                                      command=lambda: self.PRINT_SOT(),
                                      bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                      compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog11.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()



        def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):    # сортировка рабочая
            l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children()]
            l.sort(reverse=reverse)

            for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
                tv.move(k, '', index)

            tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))
        #Таблица с сотрудниками

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=("ID", "FIO driver", "nomber ud", "nomber pass", "age jods",), height=15,
                                 show="headings")
        self.tree.column("ID", width=20, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("FIO driver", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber ud", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber pass", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("age jods", width=170, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading("ID", text="ID")
        self.tree.heading("FIO driver", text="ФИО водителя эвак.")
        self.tree.heading("nomber ud", text="Номер удостоверения", command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, 'nomber ud', False))
        self.tree.heading("nomber pass", text="Номер паспорта")
        self.tree.heading("age jods", text="Трудовой стаж(лет)", command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, 'age jods', False)) # вызов сортировки
        self.tree.pack()
        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set)
        self.Treeview = self.tree
        self.id = 1
        self.iid = 1



        with open("Sotrudniki.csv", newline="") as f:
            for Sotrudniki in csv.reader(f):
                self.tree.insert("", tk.END, values=Sotrudniki)
        self.tree.bind("TreeviewSelect")


        self.tree.place()




    def init_Dobavlenie_Sotrudnika(self): #добавление сотрудника
        super().__init__(root)
        self.title("Добавить сотрудника")
        self.geometry("400x320+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        label_FIO_driver = tk.Label(self, text="ФИО сотрудника")
        label_FIO_driver.place(x=80, y=30)

        label_entry_nomber_ud = tk.Label(self, text="Номер удостоверения")
        label_entry_nomber_ud.place(x=50, y=60)

        label_entry_nomber_pass = tk.Label(self, text="Номер паспорта")
        label_entry_nomber_pass.place(x=80, y=90)

        label_entry_age_jobs = tk.Label(self, text="Трудовой стаж(лет)")
        label_entry_age_jobs.place(x=70, y=120)

        def validate(new_value):  # +++
            return new_value == "" or new_value.isnumeric()
        vcmd = (root.register(validate), '%P')
        self.FIO_driver = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.FIO_driver.place(x=180, y=30)

        self.entry_nomber_ud = ttk.Entry(self,validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.entry_nomber_ud.place(x=180, y=60)

        self.entry_nomber_pass = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_nomber_pass.place(x=180, y=90)

        self.entry_entry_age_jobs = ttk.Entry(self,validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.entry_entry_age_jobs.place(x=180, y=120)

        btn_cansel = ttk.Button(self, text="Закрыть", command=self.destroy)
        btn_cansel.place(x=240, y=250)

        btn_add = ttk.Button(self, text="Добавить", command=lambda: [self.dob_Sot(), self.ZapisSOT()])
        btn_add.place(x=70, y=250)


        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()



    def dob_Sot(self):# функция добавления в таблицу
        self.Treeview.insert('', "end", iid=self.iid, values=(self.id, self.FIO_driver.get(), self.entry_nomber_ud.get(),
                                                              self.entry_nomber_pass.get(),
                                                              self.entry_entry_age_jobs.get()))
        self.iid = self.iid + 1
        self.id = self.id + 1


    def Del_SOT(self): #Функция удаления
        row_id = str(self.tree.focus())

        self.Treeview.delete(row_id)

    def ZapisSOT(self):# Запись в файл(мои попытки сделать все самому)
        file = open("Sotrudniki.csv", "a")
        file.write(str(self.id) + ",")
        file.write(str(self.FIO_driver.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.entry_nomber_ud.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.entry_nomber_pass.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.entry_entry_age_jobs.get() + "\n"))
        self.FIO_driver.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_nomber_ud.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_nomber_pass.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_entry_age_jobs.delete(0, "end")






class ZaiavkiADM(tk.Toplevel): #окно с заявками от лица администратора

    def PRINT_ZAI(self):
        os.startfile("Zaiavki.csv", "print")

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.title("Заявления на эвакуацию")
        self.geometry("897x350+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()
        toolbar2 = tk.Frame(self, bg='#d8d9e9', bd=0)
        toolbar2.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

        btn_open_dialog9 = tk.Button(toolbar2, text="Удалить заявку", command=lambda: self.Del_ZAI(),
                                     bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog9.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog13 = tk.Button(toolbar2, text="На печать", command=lambda: self.PRINT_ZAI(),
                                     bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog13.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=("ID", "FIO driver", "nomber ud", "nomber pass", "nomber car", "Data",
                                                "Nomber_tel", "Vid"),
                                 height=15, show="headings")

        def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):  # сортировка рабочая
            l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children()]
            l.sort(reverse=reverse)

            for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
                tv.move(k, '', index)

            tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))


        self.tree.column("ID", width=25, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("FIO driver", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber ud", width=135, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber pass", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber car", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("Data", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("Nomber_tel", width=110, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("Vid", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading("ID", text="ID")
        self.tree.heading("FIO driver", text="ФИО водителя")
        self.tree.heading("nomber ud", text="Номер удостоверения", command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, 'nomber ud', False))
        self.tree.heading("nomber pass", text="Номер паспорта")
        self.tree.heading("nomber car", text="Номер машины", command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, 'nomber car', False))
        self.tree.heading("Data", text="Дата подачи заявления")
        self.tree.heading("Nomber_tel", text="Номер телефона")
        self.tree.heading("Vid", text="Вид заявления")
        self.tree.pack()

        with open("Zaiavki.csv", newline="") as f:
            for Zaiavki in csv.reader(f):
                self.tree.insert("", tk.END, values=Zaiavki)
        self.tree.bind("TreeviewSelect")


    def Del_ZAI(self):  #Удаление заявок
        row_id = str(self.tree.focus())

        self.tree.delete(row_id)




class ZaiavkaGAI(tk.Toplevel):  #Заполнение заявки от лица ГАИ

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.title("Заполнить заявку ГАИ")
        self.geometry("400x320+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Сотрудник ГАИ", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
        label1.pack()

        label_FIO_driver = tk.Label(self, text="ФИО водителя")
        label_FIO_driver.place(x=80, y=30)

        label_entry_ud = tk.Label(self, text="Номер удостоверения")
        label_entry_ud.place(x=60, y=60)

        label_entry_pass = tk.Label(self, text="Номер паспорта")
        label_entry_pass.place(x=80, y=90)

        label_entry_nomder_car = tk.Label(self, text="Номер машины")
        label_entry_nomder_car.place(x=80, y=120)

        label_Nomber_tel = tk.Label(self, text="Номер телефона")
        label_Nomber_tel.place(x=80, y=150)

        label_Data = tk.Label(self, text="Дата заполнения")
        label_Data.place(x=80, y=180)

        self.vid = "ГАИ"

        def validate(new_value):  # +++
            return new_value == "" or new_value.isnumeric()
        vcmd = (root.register(validate), '%P')

        self.entry_FIO_driver = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_FIO_driver.place(x=190, y=30)

        self.entry_ud = ttk.Entry(self, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.entry_ud.place(x=190, y=60)

        self.entry_pass = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_pass.place(x=190, y=90)

        self.entry_nomder_car = ttk.Entry(self,validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.entry_nomder_car.place(x=190, y=120)

        self.Nomber_tel = ttk.Entry(self,validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.Nomber_tel.place(x=190, y=150)

        self.Data = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.Data.place(x=190, y=180)

        btn_cansel = ttk.Button(self, text="Закрыть", command=self.destroy)
        btn_cansel.place(x=240, y=250)

        btn_add = ttk.Button(self, text="Добавить", command=self.ZapisGAI)
        btn_add.place(x=70, y=250)

        self.id1 = 1
        self.iid1 = 1

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()

    def ZapisGAI(self):  #Мои те же самые попытки все самому сделать
        file = open("Zaiavki.csv","a")
        file.write(str(self.id1)+ ",")
        file.write(str(self.entry_FIO_driver.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.entry_ud.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.entry_pass.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.entry_nomder_car.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.Nomber_tel.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.Data.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.vid) + "\n")
        file.close()
        self.entry_FIO_driver.delete(0,"end")
        self.entry_ud.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_pass.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_nomder_car.delete(0, "end")
        self.Nomber_tel.delete(0, "end")
        self.Data.delete(0, "end")
        file.close()



class Zaiavka(tk.Toplevel):  #Заполнение заявки от лица обычного человека
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_Zaiavka()

    def init_Zaiavka(self):
        self.title("Заполнить заявку")
        self.geometry("400x320+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Частное лицо", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
        label1.pack()

        label_FIO_driver = tk.Label(self, text="ФИО водителя")
        label_FIO_driver.place(x=80, y=30)

        label_entry_ud = tk.Label(self, text="Номер удостоверения")
        label_entry_ud.place(x=50, y=60)

        label_entry_pass = tk.Label(self, text="Номер паспорта")
        label_entry_pass.place(x=80, y=90)

        label_entry_nomder_car = tk.Label(self, text="Номер машины")
        label_entry_nomder_car.place(x=80, y=120)

        label_Nomber_tel = tk.Label(self, text="Номер телефона")
        label_Nomber_tel.place(x=80, y=150)

        label_Data = tk.Label(self, text="Дата заполнения")
        label_Data.place(x=80, y=180)

        def validate(new_value):  # Защита от неверных данных
            return new_value == "" or new_value.isnumeric()
        vcmd = (root.register(validate), '%P')

        self.FIO_driver1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.FIO_driver1.place(x=180, y=30)

        self.entry_ud1 = ttk.Entry(self, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd) #вызов защиты
        self.entry_ud1.place(x=180, y=60)

        self.entry_pass1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_pass1.place(x=180, y=90)

        self.entry_nomder_car1 = ttk.Entry(self, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.entry_nomder_car1.place(x=180, y=120)

        self.Nomber_tel = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.Nomber_tel.place(x=180, y=150)

        self.Data1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.Data1.place(x=180, y=180)

        self.vid1 = "Частное лицо"

        self.iid = 1
        self.id = 1

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()

        btn_cansel = ttk.Button(self, text="Закрыть", command=self.destroy)
        btn_cansel.place(x=240, y=250)

        btn_add = ttk.Button(self, text="Добавить", command=self.Zapis)
        btn_add.place(x=70, y=250)

    def Zapis(self):  # Те же самые попытки записи
        self.iid = 1 + self.iid
        self.id = 1 + self.id
        file = open("Zaiavki.csv","a")
        file.write(str(self.id)+ ",")
        file.write(str(self.FIO_driver1.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.entry_ud1.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.entry_pass1.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.entry_nomder_car1.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.Nomber_tel.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.Data1.get() + ","))
        file.write(str(self.vid1) + "\n")
        file.close()
        self.FIO_driver1.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_ud1.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_pass1.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_nomder_car1.delete(0, "end")
        self.Nomber_tel.delete(0, "end")
        self.Data1.delete(0, "end")
        self.iid = 1 + self.iid
        self.id = 1 + self.id






class Protocol(tk.Toplevel):  #Окно с таблицей где все протоколы

    def PRINT_PRI(self):
        os.startfile("Protokol.csv", "open")

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Протокол")
        self.geometry("900x350+400+300")
        self.resizable(True, True)
        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()
        toolbar2 = tk.Frame(self, bg='#d8d9e9', bd=0)
        toolbar2.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        btn_open_dialog7 = tk.Button(toolbar2, text="Заполнить протокол эвакуации",
                                     command=lambda: self.init_Dobavlenie_Protocol(),
                                     bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog7.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog9 = tk.Button(toolbar2, text="Удалить протокол", command=lambda: self.Del_Prot(),
                                     bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0, compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog9.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog14 = tk.Button(toolbar2, text="На печать", command=lambda: self.PRINT_PRI(),
                                     bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0, compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog14.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog15 = tk.Button(toolbar2, text="Поиск", command=lambda: self.Poisk_Prot(),
                                      bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0, compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog15.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=("ID", "nomber car arrest", "FIO driver", "nomber car", "adress arest",
                                                "adres stop", "entry_Data"), height=15, show="headings")

        def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):  # сортировка рабочая
            l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children()]
            l.sort(reverse=reverse)

            for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
                tv.move(k, '', index)

            tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))
        self.tree.column("ID", width=20, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber car arrest", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("FIO driver", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber car", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("adress arest", width=170, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("adres stop", width=170, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("entry_Data", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)



        self.tree.heading("ID", text="ID")
        self.tree.heading("nomber car arrest", text="Номер эвак. машины", command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, 'nomber car arrest', False))
        self.tree.heading("FIO driver", text="ФИО водителя")
        self.tree.heading("nomber car", text="Номер эвакуатора", command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, 'nomber car', False))
        self.tree.heading("adress arest", text="Место эвакуации")
        self.tree.heading("adres stop", text="Место доставки")
        self.tree.heading("entry_Data", text="Дата эвакуации")
        self.tree.pack()
        self.Treeview = self.tree
        self.id = 1
        self.iid = 1

        with open("Protokol.csv", newline="") as f:
            for Protocol in csv.reader(f):
                self.tree.insert("", tk.END, values=Protocol)
        self.tree.bind("TreeviewSelect")


    def init_Dobavlenie_Protocol(self):  #Функция добавления
        super().__init__(root)
        self.title("Заполнить протокол")
        self.geometry("400x320+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        label_nomber_car_driver = tk.Label(self, text="Номер машины")
        label_nomber_car_driver.place(x=80, y=30)

        label_entry_FIO = tk.Label(self, text="ФИО водителя")
        label_entry_FIO.place(x=80, y=60)

        label_entry_nomber_car_arrest = tk.Label(self, text="Номер эвак. машины")
        label_entry_nomber_car_arrest.place(x=55, y=90)

        label_entry_adress_arest = tk.Label(self, text="Место эвакуации")
        label_entry_adress_arest.place(x=80, y=120)

        label_entry_jail_adress = tk.Label(self, text="Место доставки")
        label_entry_jail_adress.place(x=80, y=150)

        label_entry_Data = tk.Label(self, text="Дата эвакуации")
        label_entry_Data.place(x=80, y=180)

        def validate(new_value):  # +++
            return new_value == "" or new_value.isnumeric()
        vcmd = (root.register(validate), '%P')

        self.entry_nomber_car_driver = ttk.Entry(self, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.entry_nomber_car_driver.place(x=180, y=30)

        self.entry_FIO = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_FIO.place(x=180, y=60)

        self.entry_nomber_car_arrest = ttk.Entry(self, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.entry_nomber_car_arrest.place(x=180, y=90)

        self.entry_adress_arest = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_adress_arest.place(x=180, y=120)

        self.entry_jail_adress = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_jail_adress.place(x=180, y=150)

        self.entry_Data = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_Data.place(x=180, y=180)

        btn_cansel = ttk.Button(self, text="Закрыть", command=self.destroy)
        btn_cansel.place(x=240, y=250)

        btn_add = ttk.Button(self, text="Добавить", command=lambda: [self.dob_Prot(), self.Zapis_PROT()])
        btn_add.place(x=70, y=250)

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()

    def Poisk_Prot(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.title("Поиск")
        self.geometry("400x100+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        label_Poisk = tk.Label(self, text="Поиск")
        label_Poisk.place(x=50, y=20)
        self.entry_Poisk = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_Poisk.place(x=105, y=20, width=150)
        btn_cansel = ttk.Button(self, text="Закрыть", command=self.destroy)
        btn_cansel.place(x=185, y=50)
        btn_Poisk = ttk.Button(self, text="Поиск", command=self.search())
        btn_Poisk.place(x=105, y=50)
        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()

    def search(self):  # Поиск
        search_entry_get = self.entry_Poisk.get()
        id_to_select = ()

        if search_entry_get == '':
            all_tags = root.call(str(self.tree), "tag", "names")
            tags_to_select = tuple(filter(lambda tag: search_entry_get.lower() in tag.lower(), all_tags))
            for sorted_tag in tags_to_select:
                id_to_select += self.tree.tag_has(sorted_tag)

        self.tree.selection_set(id_to_select)


    def dob_Prot(self):  #Добавление
        self.Treeview.insert('', "end", iid=self.iid,
                             values=(self.id, self.entry_nomber_car_driver.get(), self.entry_FIO.get(),
                                     self.entry_nomber_car_arrest.get(), self.entry_adress_arest.get(),
                                     self.entry_jail_adress.get(), self.entry_Data.get()))
        self.iid = self.iid + 1
        self.id = self.id + 1



    def Del_Prot(self):  #Удаление
        row_id = str(self.tree.focus())

        self.Treeview.delete(row_id)



    def Zapis_PROT(self):  # Те же попытки
        file = open("Protokol.csv","a")
        file.write(str(self.id) + ",")
        file.write((self.entry_nomber_car_driver.get()+ ","))
        file.write(str(self.entry_FIO.get()+ ","))
        file.write((self.entry_nomber_car_arrest.get()+ ","))
        file.write(str(self.entry_adress_arest.get()+ ","))
        file.write(str(self.entry_jail_adress.get()+ ","))
        file.write(str(self.entry_Data.get() + "\n"))
        self.entry_nomber_car_driver.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_FIO.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_nomber_car_arrest.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_adress_arest.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_jail_adress.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_Data.delete(0, "end")
        file.close()




class Admin(tk.Toplevel):  #Кнопка Админ
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_Admin()

    def open_dialog4(self):
        Protocol()

    def open_dialog5(self):
        Sotrudniki()

    @staticmethod
    def open_dialog6():
        ZaiavkiADM()

    def init_Admin(self):
        toolbar1 = tk.Frame(self, bg='#d8d9e9', bd=0)
        toolbar1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        btn_open_dialog4 = tk.Button(toolbar1, text="Протокол эвакуации", command=lambda: self.open_dialog4(),
                                     bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0, compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog4.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        btn_open_dialog5 = tk.Button(toolbar1, text="Сотрудники", command=lambda: self.open_dialog5(), bg="#d7d8e0",
                                     bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog5.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        btn_open_dialog6 = tk.Button(toolbar1, text="Заявления на эвакуацию", command=lambda: self.open_dialog6(),
                                     bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog6.pack(side=tk.TOP)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
    root.title("Эвакуаторное агенство")
    root.geometry("450x250+100+200")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Просто нужно интерпритировать эту функцию поиска под мой код

Comment: Я просто эту функцию понять не могу даже...

Comment: А как интерпритировать под мой код и подавно)